# Why this delegate assignment does not work and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, covariance, contravariance

I have the following sample code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.del = this.EventHandler; <-- This does not build
    }

    public void EventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public delegate void A(object sender, EventArgs e);

    private A del;
}
```

It complains about the delegate assignment. I suspect it is due to Covariance / Contravariance issues which honestly speaking is a concept that I do not fully understand.

Is there any way of making this code build? I need a generic handler for any event with any event args (inheriting from EventArgs).

Comment: Change one of them: `PropertyChangedEventArgs` in *EventHandler* method or `EventArgs` in delegate

Comment: I need a generic handler for any event with any event args (inheriting from EventArgs).

Comment: Then change `PropertyChangedEventArgs` to `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine, that this line is compiled:

```
        this.del = this.EventHandler;
```

Then, here's a problem:

```
        // since del must accept ANY EventArgs descendant, this should be possible:
        del.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
        // since del's signature IS (object, PropertyChangedEventArgs), we must convert 
        // NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs to PropertyChangedEventArgs
        // OOOPS...
```

> I need a generic handler for any event with any event args

Use handler with this signature:

```
public void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


// compiles just fine
this.Loaded += EventHandler;
this.Closing += EventHandler;
this.Drop += EventHandler;
```

Comment: This is the answer that pointed me to were the problem is in an easy way. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is that I have a generic service that receives a handler to any event as a EventHandler parameter and attaches it to an event retrieved with reflection. It works with EventArgs but it does not work with any handler receiving something inherited from EventArgs.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explication about delegate variance and covariance [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx)

> When you assign a method to a delegate, covariance and contravariance
>   provide flexibility for matching a delegate type with a method
>   signature. Covariance permits a method to have return type that is
>   more derived than that defined in the delegate. Contravariance permits
>   a method that has parameter types that are less derived than those in
>   the delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature has to match with the `delegate`. If what you are trying to do would be allowed then you could pass any type to second parameter that inherits from `EventArgs` but it actually expects `PropertyChangedEventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

That can't work like that. In your example code, your `EventHandler` method requires `e` to be of type `PropertyChangedEventArgs`, i.e. a more specific type than what the delegate has declared.

It will work the other way around, i.e. your handler can be less specific than the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

Use `PropertyChangedEventArgs` in A method Overloading

**Because while Assigning Event to any delegate. their signature must be same**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.del = this.EventHandler; <-- This does not build
    }

    public void EventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public delegate void A(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);

    private A del;
}
```